# Is there a way to prevent an irresponsible pet owner from getting another pet?

Tags: canada, pets

I hate to say it but I know someone who lives in an apartment and had a dog in the past and didn't get him groomed regularly. Now she is going to get another dog. Is there any way this can legally be prevented in BC, Canada?

Answer (score 2):

No.

The quality of care for chattel is that the animal is not starving, it is not being subjected to cruelty or pain.   Not getting a "haircut" is perhaps inexplicably not on that list of egregious grievances.